# Splash Screen Hanging After System Stops App

Tags: android, android-intent

Manifest File is

```
       android:icon="@drawable/app_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false">
     <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:launchMode="standard" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Splash screen code is

```
public class SplashActivity  extends MusicActivity {
 private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 7000;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
     @Override
     public void run() {
         /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
         Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MenuActivity.class);
         startActivity(mainIntent);
     }
 }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
```

}

When you leave the app by using the 'home' key, I fire this from the activity that is running, (it's an audio player and this is the primary activity that you can exit from)

```
    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mp != null){
        mp.pause();
        if (isFinishing()){
        mp.pause();
        }
    }
}
```

When I re-enter the app is just a few minutes things are perfect, the audio resumes where it was and so on -
However - if I walk away from the device for say an hour or so and then return and launch the app from the launcher, it freezes on the 'splash screen', no error message,no force close,it just sits there.

What should I be checking for?
Thanks

Comment: If mp isn't null and isFinishing is true you're calling mp.pause() twice. That isn't related to your problem though. My guess is that looking at the [life cycle](http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png) of an activity might help.

Comment: I've read through that until I'm blue in the face, and can't for the life of me figure out what I've got wrong and where. My other apps fire off just fine

Comment: I'd suggest debugging, and examination of the logcat. Also, if you're not loading anything during the splash screen, read [this](http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=632). He makes a lot of sense.

Comment: I tried it without the splash screen and it's doing the same thing only on a different page. Plus the client really, really wants a splash screen...

Comment: Give them the link then :) And sorry but I can't help you. The manifest looks fine.

Comment: Ok thanks anyway (and I did send him  the link...here's hoping) in the meantime I'm becoming an expert in Android Activity Lifecyle -- :-)

Comment: That's always something :)